# Keycloak v21 scaled out Azure App Service with multiple instances - Issues with infinispan

Tags: azure, keycloak, infinispan

We currently have a Keycloak deployed as an Azure App Service using at least 2 instances (scaled out) in the same App Service.

Now we have the infinispan that is configured with the azure cache stack. This also gives us access to the storage account. As soon as the instances are started up, the storage account container contains files with an IP and port, for example: 169.254.254.2:7800. With these IPs, however, it does not work to communicate with the other instances. The following errors are received from the Container:
`2023-06-23T07:21:52.815593967Z 2023-06-23 07:21:52,815 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (keycloak-cache-init) a3f459dc2b25-49850: JOIN(a3f459dc2b25-49850) sent to 0ffc70c88670-22937 timed out (after 2000 ms), on try 0 2023-06-23T07:21:54.816852500Z 2023-06-23 07:21:54,816 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (keycloak-cache-init) a3f459dc2b25-49850: JOIN(a3f459dc2b25-49850) sent to 0ffc70c88670-22937 timed out (after 2000 ms), on try 1 2023-06-23T07:21:56.817344627Z 2023-06-23 07:21:56,816 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (keycloak-cache-init) a3f459dc2b25-49850: JOIN(a3f459dc2b25-49850) sent to 0ffc70c88670-22937 timed out (after 2000 ms), on try 2 2023-06-23T07:21:58.818581617Z 2023-06-23 07:21:58,818 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (keycloak-cache-init) a3f459dc2b25-49850: JOIN(a3f459dc2b25-49850) sent to 0ffc70c88670-22937 timed out (after 2000 ms), on try 3 2023-06-23T07:22:00.820421010Z 2023-06-23 07:22:00,818 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (keycloak-cache-init) a3f459dc2b25-49850: JOIN(a3f459dc2b25-49850) sent to 0ffc70c88670-22937 timed out (after 2000 ms), on try 4 2023-06-23T07:22:02.820960997Z 2023-06-23 07:22:02,819 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (keycloak-cache-init) a3f459dc2b25-49850: JOIN(a3f459dc2b25-49850) sent to 0ffc70c88670-22937 timed out (after 2000 ms), on try 5 2023-06-23T07:22:04.820918651Z 2023-06-23 07:22:04,820 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (keycloak-cache-init) a3f459dc2b25-49850: JOIN(a3f459dc2b25-49850) sent to 0ffc70c88670-22937 timed out (after 2000 ms), on try 6 2023-06-23T07:22:06.821521635Z 2023-06-23 07:22:06,821 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (keycloak-cache-init) a3f459dc2b25-49850: JOIN(a3f459dc2b25-49850) sent to 0ffc70c88670-22937 timed out (after 2000 ms), on try 7 2023-06-23T07:22:08.822038319Z 2023-06-23 07:22:08,821 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (keycloak-cache-init) a3f459dc2b25-49850: JOIN(a3f459dc2b25-49850) sent to 0ffc70c88670-22937 timed out (after 2000 ms), on try 8 2023-06-23T07:22:10.822732003Z 2023-06-23 07:22:10,822 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (keycloak-cache-init) a3f459dc2b25-49850: JOIN(a3f459dc2b25-49850) sent to 0ffc70c88670-22937 timed out (after 2000 ms), on try 9 2023-06-23T07:22:10.822770803Z 2023-06-23 07:22:10,822 WARN  [org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS] (keycloak-cache-init) a3f459dc2b25-49850: too many JOIN attempts (10): becoming singleton 2023-06-23T07:22:10.859036526Z 2023-06-23 07:22:10,858 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view for channel ISPN: [a3f459dc2b25-49850|0] (1) [a3f459dc2b25-49850] 2023-06-23T07:22:10.878978794Z 2023-06-23 07:22:10,878 INFO  [org.infinispan.CLUSTER] (keycloak-cache-init) ISPN000079: Channel "ISPN" local address is "a3f459dc2b25-49850", physical addresses are "[169.254.254.4:7800]"`

Is it not possible to reach the other instances at all? Does the possibility of having several instances have to be solved differently?

We don't have a clue how to solve the problem.

Comment: were you able to find the solution?

Comment: @AbhinavJuneja No, unfortunately we did not find a solution for that. From my point of view, this is probably not possible for technical reasons (due to the structure of these app services). The only solution we might consider is to work with an external Infinispan.